# Check if file exists before getting contents

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have some simple ajax code that gets the contents of text file on the server.
Then puts the contents into a textarea.
It throws a 404 error in the console if the file does not exist.

So I am trying to use php.
But nothing gets returned when I use php.

NoteFileName is a string created earlier that gets the filename (e.g. myfile.txt).
addnote is the id of the textarea.

My original code that gives the 404 error (if the file does not exist):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "upload/" + NoteFileName,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        document.getElementById("addnote").innerHTML = data;
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("note does not exist");
    }
});
```

My attempt at php:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxfilenotesget.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        NoteFileName: NoteFileName,
    },
    success: function() {
    document.getElementById("addnote").innerHTML = notedata;
    }
});
```

The external php file:

```
  $filename = "upload/" . $_GET['NoteFileName'];

  if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $notedata = file_get_contents($filename);
  }
  else {
    $notedata = "";
  }
```

I also tried (and other variations of this):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxfilenotesget.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        NoteFileName: NoteFileName,
    },
    success: function(data) {
    document.getElementById("addnote").innerHTML = data;
    }
});
```

Just changed to this and get undefined in the textarea:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxfilenotesget.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        NoteFileName: NoteFileName,
        success: function(data) {
    document.getElementById("addnote").innerHTML = data;
    }
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you `echo` the `$notedata`?

Comment: You get a 404 error in the console, or you get a 404 response code in your network tab?

Comment: the 404 was in the console only. Other than that it all worked.

Comment: The echo, should that be in my original  code or the php code?

Comment: what is console.log(NoteFileName) when exist and when not exist

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused on what the issue is.  A normal user is not going to be looking at the browser console to see the 404 message

Comment: the echo should be in your php file all the way at the end after the if block closes. You are assigning a  value to the variable but not returning/echoing it.

Comment: @Taplar - I just wanted the code to be correct. Should i just ignore the 404 and go with the original code then? Does seem to be the easiest solution.

Comment: It's up to you to determine how critical a 404 is.  Any web request could theoretically return a 404.  Having a success and error handler for the ajax request to handle both cases, imo, is usually enough.

Comment: Echoing has worked. At least the first time I do it. If I repeat the action, the second time it is blank but that is likely an issue elsewhere. May thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final solution and all is working now with no errors.

The Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxfilenotesget.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {NoteFileName: NoteFileName},
    success: function(notedata) {
      document.getElementById("addnote").value = notedata;
    }
});
```

The external PHP file code:

```
$filename = "upload/" . $_GET['NoteFileName'];

if (file_exists($filename)) {
  $notedata = file_get_contents($filename);
}
else {
  $notedata = "";
}

echo $notedata;
```